# How do I pass primary key of the entry created by a django-form, to the form in next page after that

Tags: django, django-forms

My `Models.py` contains 2 models, each `Project` can have multiple `Role` (i.e. one-to-many relationship):

```
class Project(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    state_of_project = models.CharField(max_length=10, default='ongoing')
    introduction = models.TextField(blank=True)

class Role(models.Model):
    role_name =  models.CharField(max_length=30)
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null = True)
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.role_name
```

After submitting a form for model `Project`, I wanted to redirect user to fill the next form for model `Role`. The new roles added there should automatically have their foreign key `project` point towards the project created just before.

How can I make that happen? I am specifically having problem adding mechanism of passing the primary key of newly submitted entry (for model `Project`) to the next form(for model `Role`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the primary key to urls.py and get it through the views.py

for example :

```
#urls.py
path("add-role/<int:project_id>" ,views.add_role , name="add.role"),


------------

#views.py
def add_role(request , project_id):
        project = Project.objects.get(id=project_id)
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = ProjectForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                f = form.save(commit=False)
                f.project = project
                f.save()
                return redirect("projects")
            else:
                return render(request , 'add-project.html' ,{"form":form})
        return render(request , 'add-project.html' ,  {"project":project})
```

and something like this in your html:

```
<form method="post" action="{% url 'add.role' project.id %}">
 {% csrf_token %}
 <input type="text" name="role_name" />
</form>
```